# how to close already opened TCP sockets in server using node JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I trying to close already opened socket at server end but i didn't get any info regarding how to close.

Is there any way to close already opened TCP sockets in server using node

in server client model, due to some issue the connection got closed and unfortunately server don't know that the connection got closed, client initiated new connection then at server end - it will create new connection. so here i want to close already opened (old) connection

how to delete the old socket is my query. i want to delete it using node JS - is it possible ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/net.html#socketdestroyerror

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: in server client model, due to some issue the connection got closed and unfortunately server don't know that the connection got closed, client initiated new connection then at server end - it will create new connection. so here i want to close already opened (old) connection

how to delete the old socket is my query. i want to delete it using node JS - is it possible ?